# Change or switch to different editor quickly in eclipse ? ( not tabs)

Tags: eclipse, editor

Hi i many html editors in eclipse. each one provides different features. 
Is there a way i can quickly switch the editor of current opened tab, ( other than open with option in the project explorer).

Lets say abc.html is currently open. but i want to open it in different editor.  Now i have to search that file in the project explorer and then right click > open with. option.

OR
I use ctrl+shift+r to open any resource , it always opens in default editor. But i want to choose there which editor to open with" option there. :(. is there any shortcut for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can well understand wanting to open stuff just using the keyboard.

I can think of 2 solutions:

1: CTRL + SHIFT + R (select file as normal) then (still in the Open Resource dialog) TAB, TAB, ENTER and then press the down arrow key until you get the right editor

2: Keep the Project Explorer 'Link with Editor' toggle on (a button on the top right of the Project Explorer View)

Now you can easily get from the file open in the editor to the correct place in the Project Explorer view (so you can right click on it).

Hope this helps!
(I also find CTRL + F7 a useful way of switching to the Project Explorer view from an editor)

Comment: Cool. This helped me a lot. Something is better than nothing. :)